# How to write the rule: “some characters but except” in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4, lexer, except

```
ID: (['_'a-zA-Z])(['_'a-zA-Z0-9])*;
INT_LIT: 'INT';
FLOAT: 'FLOAT';
```

What I want is that ID cannot be 'INT' or 'FLOAT'
What should I do ?? Thanks
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `INT_LIT` and `FLOAT` rules higher than `ID`. When two rules match the same text, the first one wins. I.e. "INT" will always be `INT_LIT` rather than `ID` with this setup.

Comment: `INT_LIT: 'INT';`  
    `FLOAT: 'FLOAT';`  
    `ID: (['_'a-zA-Z])(['_'a-zA-Z0-9])*;`  
You mean just like this ???

Comment: Appriciated. Thanks @doublep

Comment: One more question. I wanna define a token starting and ending with 'a'. Also in the middle, it cannot be 'bc'. So I wrote `MYTOKEN: 'a' ~('bc')* 'a'`, but it didn't work. It said: "multi-character literals are not allowed in lexer sets". Can you help me ???

Comment: Grammar rules are not full-blown regexps, you cannot do too complicated stuff with them. You may want to look into rule actions and predicates. Or verify tokens afterwards. One more idea: include stuff with 'bc' in some rule *above* `MYTOKEN`: then this rule will never match tokens with 'bc'.